# Are Static resources only accessible after a user has been authenticated?

Tags: force.com-sites, static-resources, digital-experience, favicon

I am displaying favicon in the Digital Experience Site. The favicon displays correctly.  However what I am observing is that while the Login Page is loading the browser displays the  salesforce logo before  displaying the  favicon.

Does that mean static resources are only accessible after a user has been authenticated.

If yes, then is there a way to make the static resource available while the Digital Experience Site login page is loading i.e. while it is authenticating the user ?

[image]

Comment: Does the static resource has [Cache Control set to public](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pages_static_resources_create.htm&type=5)?

Comment: yes, it is public

Comment: Did you find a way to display the image without logging in ? I am stuck in a similar issue where i configure records to show a static resource which is displayed on preview mode but not in public/guest user mode

Comment: @bharathkumar. No I did not find a way to display the image without logging in.  Based on the documentation it is not possible. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pages_static_resources_create.htm&type=5